# Weird program behaviour in Python

Tags: python

When running the following code, which is an easy problem, the Python interpreter works weirdly:

```
n = input()
for i in range(n):
    testcase = raw_input()
    #print i
    print testcase[2:(int(testcase[0])+1)]+testcase[(int(testcase[0])+2):]
```

The problem consists in taking n strings and deleting a single character from them.
For example, given the string "4 PYTHON", the program should output "PYTON".
The code runs ok, but if I take out the comment mark, the statement print i makes the interpreter give an unexpected EOF while parsing. Any idea on why this happens?

EDIT: I'm working under Python 2.5, 32 bits in Windows.

Comment: Which version of python? The for loop works fine for me with 'print i' uncommented on windows python 2.6.2c1

Comment: worked fine for me on python 2.6.2 on linux.

Comment: I also got it to run without complain - Python 2.5.1 OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am yet another who has no trouble with or without the commented print statement.  The input function on the first line is no problem as long as I give it something Python can evaluate.  So the most likely explanation is that when you are getting that error, you have typed something that isn't a valid Python expression.

Do you *always* get that error?  Can you post a transcript of your interactive session, complete with stack trace?

Comment: "complete with stack trace?" This was it; when the first value was typed in it was fetched by another input() in the stack.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that the problem is the print i statement?  The code works as
expected when I uncomment that statement and run it.  However, if I forget to
enter a value for the first input() call, and just enter "4 PYTHON" right off
the bat, then I get:

```
"SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"
```

This happens because input() is not simply storing the text you enter, but also
running eval() on it.  And "4 PYTHON" isn't valid python code.

Comment: I know, "4 PYTHON" was just an example of the way strings are formatted. The interpreter gives me an EOF even if I assign a value for n.

Comment: you need raw_input; not input(). Input() expects a valid Python expression. read http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me too, give it a try...

```
n = raw_input()
n = int(n)
for i in range(n):
  testcase = raw_input()
  print i
  print testcase[2:(int(testcase[0])+1)]+testcase[(int(testcase[0])+2):]
```

Note the `n = int(n)`

PS: You can continue to use `n = input()` on the first line; i prefer raw_input.

Comment: This works, but I still don't get why it doesn't when using input().